# How to loop my For loop variable inside my string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have some 72 pics names `fun1,fun2......fun72...` So instead of writing `72 img` tags I just wanna create `img` tags using Script. But I am unable to loop between these `72` pics because I have no idea of how to call for loop variable inside a String.

> Method 1

```
// For images
let pics = document.getElementById("pics-thumbs");
let divholder = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (let i = 1; i < 73; i++) {
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.class = "img-responsive";
    img.src = "images/fun+i.jpg";
    divholder.appendChild(img);
}
pics.appendChild(divholder);
```

> Method 2

```
// For images
let pics = document.getElementById("pics-thumbs");
let divholder = document.createDocumentFragment();
for (let i = 1; i < 73; i++) {
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.class = "img-responsive";
    img.src = "images/fun" + i ".jpg";
    divholder.appendChild(img);
}
pics.appendChild(divholder);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
img.src="images/fun" + i + ".jpg";
```

Or, with EcmaScript 6,

```
img.src=`images/fun${i}.jpg`;
```

It is called *concatenation*.

Comment: oops i missed a + after my i

Comment: And does it work now? If yes you can mark as solved. If no please post additional error messages you might get.

Comment: ya its asking wait fr 10 mins to mark it as solved

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this

**DEMO**

```js
let pics = document.getElementById("pics-thumbs"),
  imgArr = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 73; i++) {

  imgArr.push(`<img class="img-responsive" src="images/fun${i}.jpg">`);
}
pics.innerHTML = imgArr.join('<br>')
```

```html
<div id="pics-thumbs"></div>
```

Comment: Nice and easy code...Thanks a lot

Comment: @GvsAkhil hearty welcome